# Make matplotlib's ylabel display CJK text vertically

Tags: python, matplotlib, localization, cjk

I'm trying to use `matplotlib` to produce a plot with labels in CJK (Japanese, in particular). Since CJK can be written vertically, I want the `ylabel` to be written this way. I found out a way to do this below, but it requires padding each character with `\n` in order to create the desired effect. However, this is hackey.

Is there a better way that, e.g., rotates each character by 90 degrees?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Make a plot with Japanese labels.
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm

# Set fonts so that labels display correctly.
pathToInstall = '/path/to/fonts'
fontFiles = fm.findSystemFonts(pathToInstall)
fontList = fm.createFontList(fontFiles)
fm.fontManager.ttflist.extend(fontList)
fp = fm.FontProperties()
fp.set_family('Noto Sans Mono CJK JP')

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('こんにちは、世界さん！', FontProperties=fp) # Fine

plt.xlabel('アイウエオ', FontProperties=fp) # Fine
plt.ylabel(
    'あ\nい\nう\nえ\nお', # How can I avoid padding each character with \n?
    FontProperties = fp,
    rotation = 'horizontal',
    verticalalignment = 'center',
    horizontalalignment = 'right'
)

plt.show()
```

[Plot showing output of above code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQVEM.png)